# Charge controller design

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

I am designing my own solar charge controller using the MPTT algorithm, having a variable solar panel voltage.

I have decided to design a buck converter that will match and convert the input resistance (from the solar panel \$ \Large \frac{V_{mpp}}{I_{mpp}} \$ ) into output resistance (\$ \Large \frac{V_{out}}{I_{out}(D2)} \$) by a change in duty ratio.

On the the other hand I want to track the MPPT of solar which uses the switch to change the duty ratio to track the MPP (maximum power point).

My problem is that though, I have designed my buck converter to have a stable 12 V output, that is not the case when I simulate it. The output voltage changes abruptly with a change in duty ratio, that results to an unstable output voltage. **I realized that when the system is tracking the maximum power point by changing the duty ratio, the output voltage also changes**.

I was asking is there something I am missing or doing wrong with concept I just explained? Or any idea which I should consider when doing such a design?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Could you _please_ parse your wall of text into actions, observations, and then questions. Your not likely to get answers until we can understand what your questions are. Statements like "on the other hand" are confusing more than helpful.

Comment: The basic idea is simple. Vary duty cycle, and measure and store charge current (output current) for each duty cycle. The duty cycle with the largest charge current is the one you want. Once you are there, you can hunt back and forth to make sure the peak doesn't move, or periodically scan through the full range of duty cycles (say once per minute). I have no real clear idea what you are talking about in your wall of text.

Comment: ok, there basic idea i was trying to explain is that when designing a charge controller using MPPT(Perturb and observation algorithm), one has to design a buck converter that will enable me to have a stable voltage output of 12V, i did that but when i simulate my system on Psim, i am able to track the MPPT using the duty ratio, but the problem is that during that tracking process, my output voltage from the converter changes, maybe it might be the fact i am using a resistor instead of a 12V battery, a vary the current as per the change in duty ratio or it should work with the resistor connecte

Comment: Fixed voltage to a fixed resistor is not MPPT. It is fixed output power. MPPT would seek to maximize the current or voltage in the resistor. But when charging a battery, MPPT would seek to maximize charge current. Battery voltage is kind of fixed over the short term. But you also have to consider charge control. When the battery is full, you no longer want to try to achieve maximum power point tracking. At that point you want to float the battery at some slightly lower voltage (assuming lead chemistry). You only want MPPT when you are able to utilize the maximum power.

Comment: @jabu: This isn't a forum and this post isn't an answer. Please add the information to your question. You need to format it properly including proper capitalisation and punctuation if you want to be taken seriously.